# switching every 2nd row value in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is a list of football games with varying stats, around 300 entries.

> ```
>     game_id    team  opp_team  avg_marks  
> 0      2919       STK     BL        122  
> 1      2919       BL      STK       114
> 2      2920       RICH    SYD       135
> 3      2920       SYD     RICH      108
> ```

I would like to add the opposition stats as a new column for each entry.  Resultant dataframe would appear like this

> ```
>     game_id    team  opp_team  avg_marks  opp_avg_marks
> 0      2919       STK     BL        122         114
> 1      2919       BL      STK       114         122
> 2      2920       RICH    SYD       135         108
> 3      2920       SYD     RICH      108         135
> ```

Any suggestions would be most welcome, I'm new to this forum.  I have tried mapping but the entry is conditional on 2 columns, game_id and opp_team.
Ideally I would add it in original spreadsheet but I created a cumulative average for the season in pandas so was hoping there would be a way to incorporate this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group on `game_id` and reverse the `avg_marks` values

```
In [725]: df.groupby('game_id')['avg_marks'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1])
Out[725]:
0    114
1    122
2    108
3    135
Name: avg_marks, dtype: int64

In [726]: df['opp_avg_marks'] = (df.groupby('game_id')['avg_marks']
                                   .transform(lambda x: x[::-1]))

In [727]: df
Out[727]:
   game_id  team opp_team  avg_marks  opp_avg_marks
0     2919   STK       BL        122            114
1     2919    BL      STK        114            122
2     2920  RICH      SYD        135            108
3     2920   SYD     RICH        108            135
```

Or, get dict mapping from `team` and `avg_marks`, then use `map` on `opp_team`

```
In [729]: df['opp_team'].map(df.set_index('team')['avg_marks'].to_dict())
Out[729]:
0    114
1    122
2    108
3    135
Name: opp_team, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've been working on that for so long